# Post form using time

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to make a form to be posted using time. I have managed to make a count time. I would like to enter a specific time to post the from etc. 12:00.
is it possible?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <span id="remain"></span>
   <form action="3.php" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
     <input type="text" name="id">
     <input type="submit" name="Go" value="submit">
   </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=counter;
  function counter() {
     seconds = 150;
     countDown();
  } 

  function countDown(){
     document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML=seconds;
     setTimeout("countDown()",1000);
     if(seconds == 0) {
        document.form1.submit();
     }else {
        seconds--;      
     }
   }    
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to be able to allow posting of a form only during a specific time in a day?

Comment: It's only possible if the user leaves the site open that long, which feels kind of silly, doesn't it?

Comment: yes! what do you suggest then?

Comment: is it better to add it and make if elses statement with the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with find current time and then compare current time with your set time on that you want to post form

**Find Current Time**

```
var currentTime = new Date ( );
var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;
```

With above code you find the current time and then compare with specific time.
If both time is equal then run the function.

Comment: is it possible to add an input to be able to insert the time of submiting form?

Comment: where should i put the time i want to be posted?

Comment: var currentTime = new Date ( );
var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this code. This is not exactly how you asked but this is the idea

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<span id="remain"></span>
<form action="test1.asp" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" name="Go" value="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=counter;
function counter()
{
    var currentTime = new Date ( );

  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );
hours=currentHours
minutes=currentMinutes
seconds = currentSeconds;

countDown();
}   

function countDown(){


document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML=hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
setTimeout("countDown()",1000);
    if(hours == 12)
        {
            document.form1.submit();
        }else {
        seconds--;      
        }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what i wanted is to add an insert time field, so it will auto post the time i want to be posted

Answer (score 1):

Change your function countDown to this. First get the current time, then calc the remaining secs to the current time and set this as the timeout time in seconds

```
function countDown(){

 //current time in seconds
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getTime();

 //find the remaining seconds from a day
 var remainingSec = n % (60 * 60 * 24);

 //find current hours set and convert to seconds
 var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
 currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
 currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;
 var currentSec = currentHours * 60 * 60;

 //set timeout time
 var timeoutTime = remainingSec - currentSec;

 if(timeoutTime > 0) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   document.form1.submit();
  },timeoutTime * 1000);
 } else {
  console.log("Sorry the time is back in the past.");
 }

}
```

Comment: what i wanted is to add an insert time field, so it will auto post the time i want to be posted